# Java Interaction not returning

Tags: java, return, interaction

I'm making code in Java to put in numbers for variables a, b, c, and a label that calculates dimensions for a ellipsoid. Typing in Ellipsoid ex1 = new Ellipsoid ("Ex 1", 1, 2, 3); should give me the following in Interactions:

```
Ellipsoid "Ex 1" with axes a = 1.0, b = 2.0, c = 3.0 units has:
 volume = 25.1327 cubic units
 surface area = 48.9366 square units
```

But it gives me nothing. It's blank. I suspect that the last return statement at the bottom is coded wrong, but I can't figure out what exactly I'm doing wrong.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ellipsoid {

   private String label = " ";
   private double a = 0;
   private double b = 0;
   private double c = 0;

   public Ellipsoid(String labelIn, double aIn, double bIn, double cIn) { 
      setLabel(labelIn);
      setA(aIn);
      setB(aIn);
      setC(cIn);
   }
   
   public String getLabel() {
      return label;
   }
   
   public boolean setLabel(String labelIn) {
      if(label != null) {
         this.label = label.trim();
         return true;
      }
         
      else {
         return false;
      }
   }
   
   public double getA() {
      return a;
   }
   
   public boolean setA(double aIn) {
      if(a > 0) { 
         this.a = a;
         return true;
      }
      else {
         return false;  
      }
   }
   
   public double getB(){
      return b;
   }
   
   public boolean setB(double bIn) {
      if (b > 0) {
         this.b = b;
         return true;
      }
         
      else {
         return false;
      }
   }
   
   public double getC() {
      return c;
   }
   
   public boolean setC(double cIn) {
      if(c > 0) {
         this.c = c;
         return true;
      }
      
      else {
         return false;
      }
   }
  
   public double volume() {
      return (4 * Math.PI * a * b * c) / 3;
   }
   
   public double surfaceArea() {
      double surfaceAreaDouble = (Math.pow((a * b), 1.6) + Math.pow((a * c), 1.6) + Math.pow((b * c), (1 / 1.6)) / 3);
      surfaceAreaDouble = 4 * Math.PI * Math.pow(surfaceAreaDouble, (1 / 1.6));
      return surfaceAreaDouble;
   }
   
   public String toString() {
      DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.0###");
      
      return "Ellipsoid \"" + label + "\" with axes a = " + getA() + ", b = " + getB() + ", c = " +getC() + " units has:\n volume = " + decimalFormat.format(volume()) + " square units" + "\n surface area = " + decimalFormat.format(surfaceArea()) + " cubic units";
   }
  
}
```

Comment: Your proposed code, `Ellipsoid ex1 = new Ellipsoid ("Ex 1", 1, 2, 3);`, just creates an object of type `Ellipsoid` and assigns it to the variable `ex1`.  It does nothing more, nothing less.  If you want to print something to the console, you have to tell it to do that.  If you want to print the return value of `ex1`'s `toString()` method, you can just call `System.out.println(ex1);` on the next line.

Comment: So by "typing in," where are you typing this?  Can you show us the code?  Or do mean something like REPL?

Comment: Please include a main method that does this.

Comment: After a quick Google search for "Java Interations", I find myself on [a tutorial for using an "Interactions pane" in DrJava](http://www.drjava.org/docs/quickstart/ch03s05.html).  If this is what you are using, the tutorial covers this on the second bullet point.  You can just type in `ex1.toString();`

Comment: Your `setA` method _never actually uses its argument_.  You never use `aIn`.

Comment: Same with `setB` and `setC` actually, although I don't think that bears directly on the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

after looking at your code, I noticed the following issues:

1. In your setter methods you are not using the right variables. You should use the method parameters in all your setters.

example:

```
public boolean setA(double aIn) {
      if(a > 0) {            // a should be aIn here
         this.a = a;              // = a should be = aIn
         return true;
      }
      else {
         return false;  
      }
   }
```

2. the surfaceArea() method has a small mistake:

   `(Math.pow((a * b), 1.6) +  Math.pow((a * c), 1.6) +  Math.pow((b * c), (1 / 1.6)) / 3);`

The last one doesn't need the "1/ 1.6" part but just "1.6" like the rest and then you need another bracket for all 3 math.pow before you divide them by 3. (also switch "cubic" and "square" words to match volume and surface correct)

After these fixes, making an object of class Ellipsoid and printing it gives the output you are looking for:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Ellipsoid ex1 = new Ellipsoid ("Ex 1", 1, 2, 3);

    System.out.println(ex1);
}
```

output:

```
Ellipsoid "Ex 1" with axes a = 1.0, b = 2.0, c = 3.0 units has:
volume = 25.1327 cubic units
surface area = 48.9366 square units
```